Videos app fails to play videos on Wayland+nvidia but it works on vlc or smplayer
My hardware specs:
CPU: Intel 9900k
GPU: PNY 4800 RTL
MEM: 32 GB
MOTHERBOARD: Gigabyte z390
After installing Ubuntu 20.04 I started a x session and videos worked ok. Then, I moved to wayland checked that nvidia driver was active and tried videos again and it failed with message: "An error ocurred: Could not initialise OpenGL support".
The weird thing is that on VLC and SMPlayer I can play same videos without problem.
What could be causing this problem?

Your observation is correct. Use VLC or a MPV derived player (such as SMPlayer). Gnome-apps (such as Totem) deteriorate since many years. While the aforementioned players updated their OpenGL layer accordingly,  Totem seems to have problems
